# MS Edge: 0: Expected identifier, string or number

Tags: vue.js, microsoft-edge, vue-cli

Having an issue viewing my project in Microsoft Edge.
The console reads: "0: Expected identifier, string or number"

The referenced line is just a blank line in chunk-vendors.js

```
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {
/* right here */  
eval("/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function(Buffer) {\n/*\nCSV Parse\n\nPlease look at the [project
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

This is a vue-cli project with modern JavaScript (ES2015+).

Comment: The issue might be caused by using some syntax which is not supported by Edge. Which version of Edge are you using? Please provide [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can have a test and see how to help. It's hard to locate the issue with only the above description.